# sqlite index name not working

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, sql-server-ce

i am working on windows mobile application.i was using sqlserverce database in my mobile application.below mentioned my working code

```
  Dim conn1 As New SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection("Data Source = " & hht_Storage & "\database\master.sdf")
        Dim cmd1 As SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand = conn1.CreateCommand()
        Dim rdr1 As SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader
conn.Open()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect
            cmd1.IndexName = "barcodeidx"
            cmd.CommandText = "barcode"
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            MsgBox(Trim(Txt_barcode.Text))
            rslt = rdr1.Seek(SqlServerCe.DbSeekOptions.FirstEqual, New Object() {Trim(Txt_barcode.Text)})
```

now i changed my database to sqlite and started coding..so i given code like this.

```
Dim conn As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source = " & hht_Storage & "\database\master.s3db")
        Dim cmd As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
        Dim rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader

 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect
            cmd.IndexName = "barcodeidx"  **'Error' Indexname is not member of System.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand**
            cmd.CommandText = "barcode"
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            MsgBox(Trim(Txt_barcode.Text))
            rslt = rdr.Seek(SqlServerCe.DbSeekOptions.FirstEqual, New Object() {Trim(Txt_barcode.Text)})
```

**'Error' seek is not member of System.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand**

how i can rectify this issue? what should i give instead of this?

Comment: AFAIK, the `Seek` command is unique to the `SqlCeDataReader`.  If you understood what the command does in order to write the original code, why are you unable to write a `Select` command to yield the same result?  You are effectively asking for a code translation for a different DB engine.

Comment: @TnTinMn so i need to just write sql query to fetch the data..

Comment: Why change db engine?

Comment: @ErikEJ sqlite faster than sqlce

Comment: I doubt it when using TableDirect with SQLCE